# Is it possible to set constraints in DataContext generated from LINQ ORM?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, orm, constraints, datacontext

I am working on a database whose tables won't have any foreign key constraints except composite primary keys for some of the tables. Is it possible to map the database using LINQ to SQL and then set the foreign key constraints in the DataContext being generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If they don't exist you just have to create them manually in the designer - use the Inheritance tool from the designer view and drag from the primary key on one table to the foreign key on the other.

Important notes:
1) both tables must have a primary key defined: see my [blog](http://conficient.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/linq-to-sql-faq-associations-to-views/) entry on this point
2) the datatypes of the two columns must match - an integer cannot join to a date